# How to update a dependency in a Quarkus app without recompiling?

Tags: java, postgresql, quarkus

### TL;DR

I am looking for a way to update a dependecy in a Quarkus app without having to recompile the entire app. I have next to no Java knowledge, but still can force the update. The question is: What is the intended "proper" approach to achieving this goal?

---

### Example

When using Keycloak 23.0.7, we are very concerned, because it has (especially) the vulnerability CVE-2024-1597 with a base score of 10.0. This alone and by itself is perceived as a problem of biblical proportions and my task is to purge this vulnerability from our system.

### Problem

The vulnerability exists in the Postgresql driver in Version 42.6.0, which happens to be part of Keycloak 23.0.7. There are two ways forward:

1. update to Keycloak 24.0.1 which ships a more recent version of the Postgresql driver where the vulnerability is fixed. (There isn't any 23.0.8.)
2. surgically replace the vulnerable postgresql-42.6.0 JAR with the fixed postgresql-42.6.2 JAR

Doing a major upgrade of some component in our system takes time and preparation. This is of course what I will ultimately do, but I have to survive until then

Surgically replacing the affected library is something I feel empowered to do right here, right now. From what I can read up on, I am supposed to to recompile Keycloak with the updated library. I can't do that either.

### Pyrrhic victory

Technically, I am able to

```
rm lib/lib/main/org.postgresql.postgresql-42.6.0.jar
wget https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/postgresql-42.6.2.jar -O lib/lib/main/org.postgresql.postgresql-42.6.0.jar
```

With rock solid faith in semantic versioning and upstream, this works. I can start and operate Keycloak, knowing I am using a good version of the Postgresql driver.

### Trying to improve

I need to at least put the proper version in the filename, i.e.

```
mv lib/lib/main/org.postgresql.postgresql-42.6.0.jar lib/lib/main/org.postgresql.postgresql-42.6.2.jar
```

This results in a broken Keycloak, because `42.6.0` is hardcoded into

- lib/lib/deployment/appmodel.dat
- lib/lib/deployment/deployment-class-path.dat
- lib/quarkus/quarkus-application.dat

I can actually `sed -i 's/42\.6\.0/42.6.2/g'` and force the issue again. However, I don't feel comfortable using `sed` on non-text files.

**Is there any Quarkus native way to update these `.dat` files in order to nicely replace the Postgresql version?**

### More explanations

Any such approach bears ample risk and fixing issues this way will eventually break the application. Still, from my point of view, this looks like a reproducible approach I can use to address issues quickly and effectively, while I wait for the powers that be to upgrade to the next major version.

I picked Keycloak as an example, because I also have to deal with this as well. I have many relatively big Java applications with similar problems.

Regularly recompiling applications that are about as big as Keycloak only in order to update some dependencies has a huge price tag attached to it. I am looking for alternatives and would very much like to use precompiled binaries.

Comment: By design, Quarkus does more work at compile time, in order that the application can do less work at run time. This gives a faster startup, smaller memory footprint, and higher throughput. Whereas ten years or twenty ago applications were often optimised for late binding of dependencies, modern applications are often deployed as immutable units (think containers), so paying the 'tax' for dynamic binding isn't a good tradeoff. 

So this is unlikely to be possible, for fundamental architectural reasons.

Comment: In general the best practice in Java is to rebuild the application with updated libraries. That's what the most used build systems for Java like Maven and Gradle automate.